# mysql query output with inverting table columns into row

Tags: mysql

I need to re-arrange the data table and output in php. The below query gives output of image 1, how to achieve the output of image 2:
MySQL Query:

```
SELECT
name,
leavetype,
SUM(Stock-Consumed) as Remaining 
from leaverecord
where (leavetype LIKE 'Casual' OR leavetype LIKE 'Earned' or leavetype LIKE 'Sick')
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Output

[image]

Required Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when leavetype = 'casual' then Stock - Consumed else 0 end) as casual,
       sum(case when leavetype = 'earned' then Stock - Consumed else 0 end) as earned,
       sum(case when leavetype = 'sick' then Stock - Consumed else 0 end) as sick
from leaverecord lr
group by name;
```

Comment: Error - Unknown column 'remaining' in 'field list'. Tried to replace 'remaining' with 'SUM(Stock-Consumed)' but did not work

Comment: @user7434582 . . . You just need to replace `remaining` with `Stock-Consumed`.

Answer (score 0):

This has solved the issue :

```
SELECT
name,
sum(IF(leavetype="Earned",Stock-Consumed,0)) as Earned,
sum(IF(leavetype="Casual",Stock-Consumed,0)) as Casual,
sum(IF(leavetype="Sick",Stock-Consumed,0)) as Sick
from leaverecord
GROUP BY 1;
```